# Clash of clan confused

Tags: clash-of-clans

Okay so can I link another account to my other account? My brother is playing and I'm afraid of erasing it because he is level 85 and he'd kill me. Not really. But I made my own Apple id and deleted and reinstalled the app but it did nothing. I want to make my own base. So can I link another device without loosing the base on the other? I really need answers!

Answer (score 1):

If your brother is connected through GameCenter, signing out will not cause any loss of game progress as long as he can sign back in later. Sign out of GameCenter account and sign into yours then try and launch the game.